# API Gateway CORS issue, with correct payload

Tags: ajax, api, amazon-web-services, cors, aws-api-gateway

I've been trying to fix this all day.

I got a Lambda function I'm trying to run when I make a POST request to the endpoint (configured with AWS API GATEWAY).

Everything runs fine, my options gets a 200 okay, my post gets a 200 okay and comes back with the data I want.

However when I get it back, it "thinks" it failed. I use JQuery for this project, and it comes back as the "fail" cb.

Looking at the console log the problem is quite clearly the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://xxxxxxxxx.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/prod/createCustomer.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

a standard CORS issue. But nothing I do seems to work. I enabled CORS on the API gateway (before that the OPTIONS would fail). the  `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':` is set to: `'*'` which should allow access from any origin. I of course deployed the new API.

I also tried not using CORS and instead enabling the AWS proxy thing, and having my response like this `{ statusCode, headers, body }` but when doing that I get no response whatsoever.

I have absolutely no clue where to start attempting to fix this. I even tried a dirty jsonp method. But still same problem. :(

The only bit of data I can find on my request that doesn't seem okay, is this: `x-cache:Miss from cloudfront`

Here's the full response headers from the POST request:

```
content-length:2312
content-type:application/json
date:Thu, 23 Mar 2017 22:15:08 GMT
status:200
via:1.1 95a477af435073615179b256d8101334.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
x-amz-cf-id:Hc6POYFO0HKB1xriSg2iH7O1po7ah926a4dQkgfSNBUZ460RoHRNuw==
x-amzn-requestid:2b5ed745-1016-11e7-b497-cb0a77cd1479
x-amzn-trace-id:Root=1-58d448ea-56717776eaa3f5389083e9ca
x-cache:Miss from cloudfront
```

Sadly as is quite obvious, the Access control headers aren't there... I assume that's the problem I'm desperately trying to fix. But I have no idea why since I set it to ' * ' during the Enable CORS step of this process.

I was able to get semi-close to a solution by manually creating a POST method (as opposed to "ANY"), then enabling CORS again, then turning on the PROXY on integration response, and set my response to: `{ statusCode, headers, body }` This will come back as a successfull event and run the right callback function in my ajax call. However, using this method I get no data back from Lambda... despite having it in "body", all I receive is an empty object.

I don't really have a preference of using CORS or manually adding headers, that's fine I won't be updating this much. I just really really need to get it functioning :( Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you got `x-cache:Miss from cloudfront` from your API, it is fine because API Gateway doesn't enable the edge cache on the cloudfront side. If you want **CORS** to work with Lambda proxy integration, you can return the status code and the headers, like,

```
{
    "statusCode": 200,
    "headers": { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "<domains you need>" }
}
```

Then, it will be like an empty response from the client side.

Comment: I tried the above-mentioned proxy method already, with the exception the value was a ```' * '``` (wildcard), and I used ```body: data``` as I do need resposne data back. But even then, I still get an error and I get no payload back.

Comment: Can you share the error you are getting from API Gateway?

Answer (score 1):

I have now idea why, but I was able to get it working. Using the following steps:

1. Enable CORS,
2. Deploy API, (can probably be skipped...)
3. Manually add POST method,
4. Enable Proxy on Integration response,
5. Deploy API again
6. change callback response to format: { statusCode: 200, headers: {}, body: {} }
7. use JSON.parse() to parse your payload.

This is definitely not a perfect answer. For some reason turning on the Proxy modified how my Lambda function received data, so I had to Stringify it to not cause an error. I can't offer an explanation why this happened.

The headers I used were:

```
"Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "DELETE,GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,PATCH,POST,PUT",
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
```

A better solution to this would also be a way to do this just using CORS. As you don't have to manually insert headers in all your responses. But I couldn't get that working. So please, if someone knows a better solution to this post it!